# Automatically Send an Email when Exception is raised in asp.net MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, exception, email

I am trying to come up with a way to email a dev team when an exception occurs on a web page that I am developing.  I heard of ELMAH, but I was hoping to use an internal Microsoft library to try and do that.  I thought I saw an article online with a library, but I can't seem to find it (saw it last Friday and I can't seem to find it).  If you could even point me to a tutorial of some kind, then I would appreciate it.

Comment: Downgrade?  Was it that dumb a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

many logging frameworks are capable of sending an email on a logged exception.

MS wrote the Enterprise Library: use the email trace listener

[Enterprise Library: Logging Block and Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627557/enterprise-library-logging-block-and-email)

or you can use a 3rd party such as log4net : smtp appender
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Elmah is not MS but here is a tutorial for that
http://www.storm-consultancy.com/blog/development/tools-plugins/setup-email-alerts-from-elmah-when-exceptions-are-raised/

enjoy

Comment: Good comment.  That being said, I have a dumb questions.  Do I have to add a NEW listener?  I already have a listener, but it doesn't have the correct DLL as deliniated in the stackoverflow post you showed me.  Can I add another listener this time with the email logger?

Comment: from my understanding you can multiple listeners configured. so it can log to a db, email and file. So either change your current listener or add the email one

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem using ELMAH, it is very stable.

Here is a good post to handle the error and send email:
http://www.codecapers.com/post/Error-Handling-in-MVC-with-ELMAH.aspx