# Open source exception logging solution with email ability for C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, error-logging

Can anybody recommend any open source or free exception .net logging solutions that have the capability to log and email the exceptions to the developer?

This is for a c# winforms application.

Thanks

Comment: Be careful sending emails like this from clients.  You can easily end up with tens of thousands of emails arriving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already suggested, [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/features.html) has this capability and [so](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Mail_target) does [nlog](http://nlog-project.org/).

The Enterprise-library logging block can also be configured to send mails as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627557/enterprise-library-logging-block-and-email).

I suggest you use the logging abstraction [Common.Logging](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/) so you can switch between logging implementations without the need to change your code (e.g. switch between log4net,  nlog and enterprise-lib).

Answer (score 0):

Apache [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) is a good logging framework with the ability to send emails: http://sradack.blogspot.com/2007/09/have-log4net-send-email-when-error.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/).

> The Apache log4net library is a tool to help the programmer output log statements to a variety of output targets. log4net is a port of the excellent Apache log4j™ framework to the Microsoft® .NET runtime. We have kept the framework similar in spirit to the original log4j while taking advantage of new features in the .NET runtime.

Check out the [config examples](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html) to see how to configure email among other things.